# switch UIViewController In iOS

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I have three UIViewController :A, B, C

I goto B from A

I goto C from B

how can I goBackTo A from C Without through B?

```
//in a.m
B* b =[B alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:b animated:YES];
[b release];
//in b.m
C* c=[C alloc] init];
[self presentModalViewController:c animated YES];
[c release];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am actually not sure whether this works without a navigation controller. If not, you can dismiss b and c using a delay.

```
[self popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

**EDIT:**

As stated below, that won't work. Use `[self dismissmodalviewcontroller:animated:]` inside of a delay to do what you want.

Comment: It wouldn't work without a navigation controller as it is a method from the `UINavigationController` class.

Comment: I expected that. Well,he can use [self dismissmodalviewcontroller:animated:] inside of a delay. (It will not dismiss both of them without the delay because it cannot process two dismisses at once and will ignore the second)